# dynamic rows and columns inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, simplepie

I'm trying, but I'm stucked with the logic... so, I have this:

```
$max_items=10;

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';

foreach ($feed->get_items(0, $max_items) as $item): 

echo '<td>';
echo $some_value; 
echo '</td>';

endforeach; 

echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

I want to show the results like this:

```
[1][2]
[3][4]
[5][6]
[7][8]
[9][10]
```

I have to use a while statement? A for loop? Inside or outside the foreach code?

I really don't get it...

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a *very simple* example of how to do this sort of HTML building.

```
<?php

$data = range( 'a', 'z' );
$numCols = 2;

echo "<table>\n";
echo "\t<tr>\n";

foreach( $data as $i => $item )
{
    if ( $i != 0 && $i++ % $numCols == 0 )
    {
        echo "\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n";
    }
    echo "\t\t<td>$item</td>\n";
}

echo "\t</tr>\n";
echo '</table>';
```

This way, you can change $numCols to be 3 or 4 (or any number) and always see that number of columns in the output, and it does so *without* using an nested loop.

Comment: thanks Peter!!! that Modulo operator and that $i => $item works 100%, really thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link to [Displaying Recent Posts On a Non-WordPress Page](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/11/15/displaying-recent-posts-on-a-non-wordpress-page). I think what you may be looking for is a way to loop over the objects get methods. For that you will need a nested loop and some sort of reflection.

Comment: Nope.. but thanks, I already have simplePie working fine with custom fields and customized atom tags. I just don't know how to break the results in different rows... I need some rest and more php lessons.

Answer (score 0):

I was just recently working with [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) on the February release of [Cogenuity](http://www.dynamicalsoftware.com/cogenuity) so this is still fresh in my mind.

- Your `$some_value` variable never gets initialized.
- The $item object will have such methods as `get_permalink(), get_title(), get_description()`, and `get_date()`

Comment: Hi Gleen, thanks! But this is a snippet of my code.. I have something like this before that piece:
$max_items =10;
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url(array(
 'http://xxxx.com/test/tag/destaque/?feed=atom' 
));
$feed->set_item_class('SwapDates'); 
$feed->strip_htmltags(false);